# Error in app.module when loading page, Error: Unexpected value 'id' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

When I run my code the compiler is happy but the web console gives this error below. Based on the error I assume I have a mistake in the app.module file that it has or is missing something but I cannot work out what. Below is the error and my app.module file.

```
 Error: Unexpected value 'id' declared by the module 'AppModule'  vendor.bundle.js:237504:21
    ZoneAwareError http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:237504:21
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata/< http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25675:40
    forEach self-hosted:252:13
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25673:13
    JitCompiler.prototype._loadModules http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:63174:41
    JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:63134:47
    JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:63100:16
    PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48289:16
    PlatformRef_.prototype.bootstrapModule http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48264:16
    [827] http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:6872:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:53:12
    [1529] http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:881:18
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:53:12
    webpackJsonpCallback http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:24:23
    <anonymous>
```

App module

```
    /* !!! System Imports !!! */
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

//Needed for special routes handling - 
import { routing }       from './app.routing';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
];

import { TabsModule, PaginationModule, BsDropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';

//Third Party Components
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective, FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule  } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import {ToastModule} from 'ng2-toastr';

/* *** Project Imports *** */
//Our Own App Services/Components
import { UserAuthService }      from './services/user-auth.service';
import { RenewalDocumentService } from './services/renewal-document.service';
import { RenewalOptionsService } from './services/renewal-options.service';
import { RememberMeService } from './services/remember-me.service';
import { AppMessagingService } from './services/app-messaging.service';


import { UserProfileComponent }   from './userarea/user-profile.component';
import { UserLoginComponent }   from './userarea/user-login.component';
import { UserLogoutComponent }   from './userarea/user-logout.component';
import { HomePageComponent }    from './userarea/home-page.component';
import { DocumentClassViewComponent }    from './userarea/document-class-view.component';
import { DocumentClassWithUpdatesComponent }    from './userarea/document-class-with-updates.component';
import { FileUploadComponent} from './userarea/file-upload.component';
import { ZipsUploadComponent} from './userarea/zips-upload.component';
import { UserGuideUploadComponent} from './userarea/userguide-upload.component';

import { SimpleDemoComponent} from './userarea/simple-demo';
import { RenewalClassificationListComponent } from './userarea/renewal-classification-list.component';

import { ZipListComponent } from './userarea/zip-list.component';
import { ZipYearComponent } from './userarea/zip-year.component';

import { RenewalCatFileistComponent } from './userarea/renewal-cat-filelist.component';
import { AdminFileListComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-file-list.component';
import { AdminFileRowComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-file-row.component';

import { DisclaimerComponent }   from './userarea/disclaimer.component';
import { ContactUsComponent }   from './userarea/contact-us.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent }   from './userarea/privacy-policy.component';
import { TsAndCsComponent }   from './userarea/ts-and-cs.component';
import { FaqsComponent }   from './userarea/faqs.component';
import { WebLinksComponent }   from './userarea/web-links.component';

import { CurrentYearViewComponent }   from './userarea/current-year-view.component';
import { RenewalYearViewComponent }   from './userarea/renewal-year-view.component';
import { RenewalYearSummaryComponent }   from './userarea/renewal-year-summary.component';
import { ArchiveYearsViewComponent }   from './userarea/archive-years-view.component';


import { UpdatesClassesViewComponent }    from './userarea/updates-classes-view.component';
import { UpdatesClassViewComponent }    from './userarea/updates-class-view.component';
import { UpdatesClassificationListComponent } from './userarea/updates-classification-list.component';
import { UpdatesCatFileistComponent } from './userarea/updates-cat-filelist.component';

import { UrllinkResetPasswordComponent } from './userarea/urllink-reset-password.component';
import { UrllinkActivateUserComponent } from './userarea/urllink-activate-user.component';

import { AdminOptionsComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-options.component';


import { AdminUserListComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-user-list.component';
import { AdminUserRowComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-user-row.component';
import { AccessLogComponent } from './userarea/admin_reports/access-log.component';
import { DocSearchComponent } from './userarea/doc-search.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './userarea/nav-bar.component';
import { NavBarRightComponent } from './userarea/nav-bar-right.component';

import { AdminBatchUserCreateComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-batch-user-create.component';
import { AdminManageUserComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-manageuser.component';
import { UserChangepasswordComponent } from './userarea/user-changepassword.component';
import { UserForgottenpasswordComponent } from './userarea/user-forgottenpassword.component';
import { AdminAppConfigComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-app-config.component';
import { AdminGraphFileViewComponent } from './userarea/admin_reports/admin-graph-file-view.component';

// ADS added
//import { AdminUserTableComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-user-table.component';
import { AdminUserTableComponent } from './adminusertable/adminusertable.component';
import { AdminUserReportComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-userreport.component';
import { AdminReportByUserComponent } from './userarea/admin_reports/admin-reportbyuser.component';
import { AdminReportsComponent } from './userarea/admin_reports/admin-reports.component';

import { AdminNewFileListComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-newfile-list.component';
import { AdminNewFileRowComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-newfile-row.component';

import { AdminNewUserTableComponent } from './userarea/admin_options/admin-newuser-table.component';


import { NewUserTablecolumnsComponent } from './grid/NewUserGrid/newusertablecolumns.component';
//Angular CLI bootstrapping the App
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';

import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { MultiselectDropdownModule } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';

// import { UserFilter } from '../_directives/UserFilter';
// import { AuthGuard } from '../guards/index';

import { ExportToExcel } from './services/index'; // EmailService, EventService,
import { NewUserGrid} from './grid/index';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations:
  [
    /* App Components*/
    AppComponent,

    /* Other project components*/
    UserLoginComponent, UserLogoutComponent, HomePageComponent, FileUploadComponent, ZipsUploadComponent, UserGuideUploadComponent, DocumentClassViewComponent,
    SimpleDemoComponent, FileSelectDirective, RenewalClassificationListComponent, RenewalCatFileistComponent, DisclaimerComponent, RenewalYearViewComponent,
    ArchiveYearsViewComponent, RenewalYearSummaryComponent, CurrentYearViewComponent, UpdatesClassesViewComponent, UpdatesClassViewComponent,
    UpdatesClassificationListComponent, UpdatesCatFileistComponent, UrllinkResetPasswordComponent, UrllinkActivateUserComponent, NavBarComponent,
    NavBarRightComponent, UserChangepasswordComponent, UserForgottenpasswordComponent, ContactUsComponent, PrivacyPolicyComponent, TsAndCsComponent, FaqsComponent,
    WebLinksComponent, DocumentClassWithUpdatesComponent, UserProfileComponent, ZipListComponent, ZipYearComponent, DocSearchComponent,

    /* Admin Option Components*/
    AdminOptionsComponent, AdminUserListComponent, AdminBatchUserCreateComponent, AdminFileListComponent, AdminFileRowComponent, AdminUserTableComponent, AdminManageUserComponent,

    /* Admin Report Components */
    AccessLogComponent,AdminUserRowComponent, AdminGraphFileViewComponent, AdminAppConfigComponent, AdminUserReportComponent, AdminReportByUserComponent,
    AdminReportsComponent,

    AdminNewFileListComponent, AdminNewFileRowComponent, AdminNewUserTableComponent, AdminUserTableComponent, NewUserTablecolumnsComponent,
    FileDropDirective, FileUploader, ToasterModule, ToasterService, DataTablesModule, MultiselectDropdownModule, ExportToExcel, NewUserGrid
    //ADS. We no longer use these files
    //BasicSingleFileComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing,
    ToastModule,
    ChartsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule,
    TabsModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),
    Ng2TableModule
  ],
  providers: [ UserAuthService,
    RenewalDocumentService,
    RenewalOptionsService,
    AppMessagingService,
    CookieService,
    RememberMeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If anyone can please advise on how I can debug this it would be greatly appreciated

Any advice suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your imports section you are using `routing` and

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),
```

please use any one. either make routing module separate or make it in same appmodule.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing,
    ToastModule,
    ChartsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule,
    TabsModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),
    Ng2TableModule
  ],
```

keep `routing` in the last of all modules in the import section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have corrected this.

What I have also worked out is that Components, Services and Modules all need to be defined in different areas of the app.module file as shown below, for the type of error above.

import { MyComponentb } from './mycomponent.component';
import { MyModule  } from './mymodule.module';
import {MyService } from './myservices.service';


Components are only defined under @NgModule({   declarations:
  [MyComponent]

Modules are only defined under 
 imports: [MyModule]

And Services are only defined under
providers[ MyService]